# Display video with VlcDotNet library

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, video

I have made a C# Windows Forms Application in Visual Studio 2012 and added dlls from this webpage: http://vlcdotnet.codeplex.com/
I have already gotten video to work with this code:

```
VlcControl player = new VlcControl();
Vlc.DotNet.Core.Medias.MediaBase media = new 
    Vlc.DotNet.Core.Medias.PathMedia(@"path\movie.avi");
player.Media = media;
player.Play();
```

But that displays it in another window and I have no control over that. How would I embed the video in my form?

I have not found any documentation on how to do this programmatically. Most people in tutorials have some sort of vlc control listed in their toolbox, but I haven't, so I would need to do that with code.

I have tried using panel as VlcControl's parent:

```
player.Parent=panel1;
```

Movie still plays, but there is no video, only sound.
What kind of container should I use and how to make it show the video?

More information:
Here: [VLC.DotNet Control Hosted in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23322270/vlc-dotnet-control-hosted-in-wpf) it is said that it is possible to embed video inside WindowsFormsHost element in WPF. However, in Windows Forms Application, there is only ElementHost available to me. Could I use that to embed videos and if yes, how?

Comment: Do you have a `VlcContext` instance?

Comment: @Asad Yes. What should I do with it?

Comment: Nothing, I was just checking you'd initialized it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have found the solution. I needed to add `player` to panel's controls and set the player size. Here it is, if anyone will ever need it:

```
player = new VlcControl();

panel1.Controls.Add(player);

player.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
player.ImeMode = System.Windows.Forms.ImeMode.NoControl;
player.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
player.Name = "test";
player.Rate = 0.0F;

player.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(1024, 768);

Vlc.DotNet.Core.Medias.MediaBase media = new 
    Vlc.DotNet.Core.Medias.PathMedia(@"path\movie.avi");
player.Media = media;
player.Play();
```