# VB.Net VLC Player documented usage not quite working

Tags: vb.net, windows, media-player, vlc, libvlc

I'm trying to use the VlcDotNet library to embed a small media player into a VB.Net forms-based project.

Mainly I'm following the solution that I found here:
[Display video with VlcDotNet library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23585681/display-video-with-vlcdotnet-library)
except that I've had to translate from C# to VB.

Having followed the instructions to the letter, there are two lines of the code which simply aren't recognised and won't compile. Certain methods of the Vlc.DotNet.Core code simply aren't accepted as valid.

Having used NuGet to get 4 Vlc.DotNet packages (.Core, .Core.Interops, .Forms and .Wpf), my complete code (excluding the very basic design of one button and one panel) is below. The compiler won't compile it, because it says there are 2 errors.

Firstly, "Type Vlc.DotNet.Core.Medias.MediaBase is not defined" (for the 'Dim newMedia as...' line)

Secondly, "'Media' is not a member of 'Vlc.DotNet.Forms.Control" (for the '.Media = newMedia' line)

Almost all the methods of the VlcControl are present, but I can't see why certain elements, such as the Media method, are simply not there?

Any suggestions would be extremely welcome.

Thanks

```
Imports Vlc.DotNet.Core
Imports Vlc.DotNet.Core.Interops
Imports Vlc.DotNet.Forms
Imports Vlc.DotNet.Wpf


Public Class Form1

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim player As New Vlc.DotNet.Forms.VlcControl

    Panel1.Controls.Add(player)

    With player
        .BackColor = Color.Blue
        .ImeMode = Windows.Forms.ImeMode.NoControl
        .Location = New System.Drawing.Point(0, 0)
        .Name = "test"
        .Rate = 0.0F
        .Size = Panel1.Size

        Dim newMedia As Vlc.DotNet.Core.Medias.MediaBase = New Vlc.DotNet.Core.Medias.PathMedia("E:\TempTest.mov")

        .Media = newMedia
        .Play()
    End With

End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: The new Vlc.DotNet library (Nuget: Vlc.DotNet.Wpf/Core/Core.Interops/Forms) uses a *completely* different setup to the old one. I can provide you with a working sample for the new library, but I'm afraid it'll be in C#. Would that be useful enough to qualify as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

I had try to convert out from C# and below are the new library files using method:

```
Public myvlc As New VlcControl
myvlc.Dock = DockStyle.None
myvlc.Size = New Size(myscreen.Bounds.Width, myscreen.Bounds.Height)
myvlc.Location = New Point(0, 0)
Me.Controls.Add(myvlc)
AddHandler myvlc.VlcLibDirectoryNeeded, AddressOf LibNeeded


Private Sub LibNeeded(ByVal Sender As Object, ByVal e As   VlcLibDirectoryNeededEventArgs)
    e.VlcLibDirectory = New IO.DirectoryInfo("C:\lib\x86\")
End Sub
```

Please download the Video Codec lib from the same website where you get the vlc.dotnet.

Comment: This isn't an answer. And "download from..." sounds awfully like an answer which will disappear tomorrow.